# How do you format the alignment for the Unix script statement

Tags: shell

How do we format the alignment for the Unix script statement -

```
printf("% -30s,%-16s,%-15s,%-1s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4)
```

The alignment is haphazard and I need to make all the columns left aligned.

Comment: Is that a `printf()` statement from an `awk` script?  What's wrong with the plain shell script analog: `printf "%-30s,%-16s,%-15s,%-1s\n" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"`, where I'm assuming that arguments 1-4 are the values to be printed?  Or, more plausibly, since you have comma separators, `printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"`?

Comment: yes that's an awk script. even though it is already left aligned. the text is haphazard . we need to pad spaces between two columns . for eg my output is as shown below:

Comment: Can you show a small example of what you have as inputs, and what you actually get as output, and what you want to get?  The (POSIX) `printf` command can probably be used to do the formatting, but without more information, it isn't possible to do better than the hand-waving in my first comment.